# How do I unique the result in this query?

Tags: github

I'm using this github query to lookup all contributors to a repo,

```
{
  repository(name: "DocsGPT", owner: "arc53") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "main") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                author {
                  name
                  email
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) to test the query.

How can I get a unique output of the results?